# WHY? AndroidStudio+Gradle = 46000 method count VS Eclipse+Ant = 43000 method count

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I'm compiling a project using proguard with Google Play Services 7.5, Android 21 and Support v4 library. My method count is higher if i compile it with android studio than if i compile it with eclipse. I used a program called dex-method-count into two apks generated with both programas and i discovered that this is the reason:

AndroidStudio+gradle:

```
    support: 5416
        v4: 2755
            app: 594
            content: 33
            graphics: 96
                drawable: 96
            internal: 74
                view: 74
            media: 123
                session: 60
            os: 13
            text: 17
            util: 166
            view: 1024
                accessibility: 204
            widget: 615
        v7: 2661
            app: 232
            appcompat: 1
            internal: 1757
                app: 77
                text: 3
                transition: 1
                view: 628
                    menu: 536
                widget: 1047
            view: 24
            widget: 647
```

Eclipse + Ant:

```
    support: 2073
        v4: 2073
            app: 549
            content: 21
            media: 123
                session: 60
            os: 11
            util: 157
            view: 757
                accessibility: 204
            widget: 455
```

As you can see in the first option it is adding a lot of methods from support v7, why? how can this be avoided?

Thanks

PD: My build gradle files for the library and the application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

the application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.launcher"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':caponateLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: Post the build.gradle content, please.

Comment: done, i'm compiling with same version of gps and v4 in both eclipse and android studio, and using the same proguard settings and same api level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services` has dependencies on `com.google.android:wearable` and `com.google.android:play-services-cast`. Each of those have dependecies on `v7` support libraries (`recyclerview-v7` and `mediarouter-v7`, respectively).

Unless you are using just about everything in the Play Services SDK, you will be much better served using finer-grained dependencies (see "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable" on [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)). Not only will this get rid of a bunch of Play Services bloat, but it may get rid of your `v7` methods, depending on what bits of Play Services you are using.

BTW, `compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'` is pointless, unless you are still using Maps V1, which would be rather surprising at this stage. `compileSdkVersion 22` would be a better choice.